# How to rotate text with hummus recipe JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, hummus.js

I want to add text "PO-83274323" to existing PDF file but I want to rotate it.

```
const HummusRecipe = require('hummus-recipe');
const pdfDoc = new HummusRecipe('046303BO.pdf', 'PO-83274323_046303BO.pdf');
pdfDoc
    // edit
    .editPage(1)
    .text('PO-83274323', 0, 0)
    .endPage()
 
    // end and save
    .endPDF();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Add your own efforts such as coding approaches and docs research.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :))

```
.text('PO-00056249', 240, 80, {
        color: '#000000',
        fontSize: 7,
        align: 'center center',
        opacity: 0.8,
        rotation: 270
          })
```